# In spite of sync is disabled, sync icon is shown in notification bar forever!

Tags: sync, samsung, notification-bar, bugs

I am talking about Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos2 (GT-S6802). The undesirable thing is that Sync icon is always shown in notification bar. I checked Accounts and sync settings many times to make sure Auto sync is disable.

[image: screen-shot]

In above screen-shot you can see that Auto sync is not enabled. However, Sync icon/symbol is shown at notification area.

I also tried after enabling and re-disabling Auto sync options, restarting many times but sync icon at notification bar po-pups sometimes (1 min) after booting and remains forever.

So, Why this is happening and **How do I get rid of it?** (Is there any thing I'm missing?)

---

Note: I also tried turn-off data connection and background data as well but not succeed.

Comment: Unchecking "Show Notifications" under Settings -> Apps -> All Apps -> <Your Sync App> and then checking it should remove it from Status Bar. You can leave it unchecked but it would make it would never ever show up in Status Bar and neither any notification in Notification Bar. But that's one option. // The other option is to force-stop the app which would also remove the icon, but that's a temporary solution.

Comment: @Firelord This is android 2.3 and no such option is available  for phone mentioned in question

Comment: I see. Then it would be better if you mention this detail in the question, and not in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue - I have an old Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.3.6.  I *think* somehow an app got updated when I was on WiFi, but I didn't know what it was. I noticed a "sync" icon appeared and would not go away.

I finally realized I could go to Settings → Applications → Battery Use, and find out that YouTube was the culprit.

Then I could force stop that app and the icon went away, but it came back after a reboot, so I also uninstalled YouTube app updates.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is go to your google account, cancel the sync process and untick all google items for syncing

Answer (score -2):

I had a same problem, by uninstall google play service this symbol can be removed

Comment: Good find, but that's not incredibly useful, because many apps won't work without Google Play Services.

Comment: @DanHulme If it can be uninstalled at all, on a non-rooted device, as it's a system app. Anyway, for 99% of users, even trying to uninstall Google Play Services is a **horrendous** idea!

Answer (score -2):

I uninstalled YouTube and it went away.